# Delay a clock to give time for the input to settle?

Tags: clock, shift-register

I have a numerical keypad that I want to feed into a shift register to display the last three numbers I have pushed. My numeric keypad has ten lines, each of which connects to a common on a button press, which feeds into a 10 line -> BCD encoder.

The problem is, how do I clock the shift register? If I clock it with the keypad itself, the input hasn't yet settled and it gets inconsistent results. What I need is to clock the shift register with a delay. How can I do this with the fewest components? I don't want to use a microcontroller as this device needs to be field supportable by a tech without microcontroller knowledge.

Comment: Can you please add a schematic?

Comment: Using a microcontroller doesn't require that a field tech have microcontroller knowledge.  If you use a microcontroller, chances are the only other parts you will have are ESD protection.  If you really need to service the keypad rather than replace it, use a DIP microcontroller and socket it (I would not, the socket is probably a greater reliability risk than the microcontroller is).

Comment: What shift register(s) are you using?

Comment: This sounds like a [debouncing issue](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm). If you are dead-set on avoiding a microcontroller and don't want to deal with a bunch of capacitors, then I recommend using an [IC designed for the task](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/2/287.html).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to add a delay is with gates themselves:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6YwqW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you have some gate IC's laying around, you can use these to add a delay. With two NOT gates, lets say the delay is 10ns, with 2 of them, you'd get 20ns. With 4 not gates you'd  have 40 ns delay.

An AND gate can also be used if the inputs are tied together.

If you needed delays greater a micro second then that might not work, because you'd need a large amount of gates, a one shot 555 timer might be better.

Comment: It sounds like the OP may need a delay on the order of 10ms for debouncing, so I kind of doubt that gates will provide a sufficient delay. A 555 timer would, but they would need 10 of them (or 5× 556 timers).

Comment: The bigger question is how to debounce the keypad in a simple logic circuit.  Using gate delays will help meet the setup requirements for the input on the shift register, but won't produce a practical circuit.   A real solution ends up way more complex and unreliable with a discrete gate solution instead of a microcontroller or CPLD.

Comment: @CalebReister Only one would be needed if the inputs all diode-OR to the trigger input.

Comment: @DeanFranks I agree, although there are [several ways](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/2/287.html) to debounce multiple switches simultaneously without using complex logic.

Comment: @PhilG Good point, but that doesn't help with the debouncing issue, which appears to be the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

sense current in the common line either the common line to the pad, or the common of the pull-up/down resistors and use that signal to start the delay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLxbH0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

shown above are current detectors built from transistors, you can use either one depending on which polarity of signal suits best, they do reduce the amplitude of the signal by 0.6V each, but most logic parts should not be bothered by that.

The delay can be a 555 or maybe just an R-C delay.